# php contact form email information

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, contacts

i made a contactform and it almost works fine.

```
<?php
$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
$contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
$contact_tel = $_POST['contact_tel'];
$contact_call = $_POST['contact_call'];
$contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];
$formcontent=" Von: $contact_name \n Tel.: $contact_tel \n Rückruf: $contact_call \n Nachricht: <br> $contact_message";
$recipient = "jonathanrobrecht@googlemail.com";
$subject = "Kontaktformular";
$from = '$contact_email';
$mailheader = "Von: $contact_email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

That is the php an when i sned an email i got in the email client the information of the subject but not who send the email(well the adress of my webserver is shown) but i want that the email which is filled in is the email.

I tried this:

```
$subject = "Kontaktformular";
$from = '$contact_email';
```

$subject does work, but from does not, how do i fixe this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be: $mailheader = $mailheader = "From: $contact_email \r\n";" ?

Comment: yes you are right, i translated this word into german....badam :D thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$from = '$contact_email';
```

Should be

```
$from = "$contact_email";
```

If you single quote it, PHP interprets it literally as '$contact_email'; if you double-quote it, it adds in the value of the variable instead.

Comment: I cant't see that $from is even used in his/her code after declaring the variable.

Comment: I figured that (s)he probably wasn't using it because it wasn't being initialised properly.

Comment: @andrewsi - didnt change anything... for better understanding i uploaded an image: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg62/scaled.php?server=62&filename=unbenannt4fj.jpg&res=landing in need the red informations.

Comment: I _think_ for a `From` header, you need to do it in English, so change your `Von:` over. And you're not setting anything that will change the `mailed-by` line.